# JAVA New values to array in second loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have problem with int array. I put in array measured values in loop and when array is full, index is set to 0 and increments by 1. 
But in second loop array is not filled with new values. 
I try to clear data with this:

```
RedData=new int[1001];
```

but nothing happens. Program is OK in all loops but I have problem only with this array.

Would you recommend me something?

Comment: Post your full code snippet so that others would be able to help you in a better way.

Comment: I'd recommend you to post full codes here

Comment: Without code it would be hard to assume your scenario? Post you code

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve] to complete your question. Without it, this can't be answered. For now, this question is not valid

Answer (score 0):

it is app for android
in main activity i call method parse(data)

```
int[] RedData = new int[1001];
int peak1=0,peak2=0,peak3=0,index1=0,index2=0,index3=0,pr1,pr2;
double pulseRate=0;
private int i =0;
private OxiParams mOxiParams;
private OnDataChangeListener mOnDataChangeListener;



public void parse(int[] packageDat) {

    int  red,ir;

    red= 256*256*packageDat[1]+256*packageDat[2]+packageDat[3];
    ir = 256*256*packageDat[4]+256*packageDat[5]+packageDat[6];

    RedData[i] = red;
    if(i>20) {
        if (RedData[i - 10] >= RedData[i - 20] && RedData[i - 10] > RedData[i] && peak1 == 0) {
            peak1 = RedData[i - 10];
            index1 = i - 10;
        }
        if (peak1 > 0 && i > (index1 + 25) && peak2 == 0) {
            if (RedData[i - 10] >= RedData[i - 20] && RedData[i - 10] > RedData[i]) {
                peak2 = RedData[i - 10];
                index2 = i - 10;
            }
        }
        if (peak2 > 0 && i > (index1 + 25) && peak3 == 0) {
            if (RedData[i - 10] >= RedData[i - 20] && RedData[i - 10] > RedData[i]) {
                peak3 = RedData[i - 10];
                index3 = i - 10;
            }
        }
        pr1 = (index2 - index1) * 10;
        pr2 = (index3 - index2) * 10;
        if (pr1 > 0 && Math.abs(pr1 - pr2) < 100) {
            pulseRate = 60000 / (pr1 + pr2);
        }
    }

    if((int)pulseRate != mOxiParams.pulseRate )
    {
        mOxiParams.update((int)pulseRate);
        mOnDataChangeListener.onSpO2ParamsChanged();
    }

    if(i<1000)
    {
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        i=0;
        RedData=new int[1001];
    }
}
```

here is code files [Github SPO2 Android](https://github.com/dbarvik/SPO2-Android)